# C# Auto Move to Next Line of Multiline Textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I've been tasked with creating a feedback dialogue box to work in conjunction which offers the user simple text based feedback on what operations are occurring. E.g. master switch turned on, hob 1 turned on. I got the text response to display in a multiline textbox, but can only get it to write on the first line therefore overwriting whatever was previously there before. Is there a way to get new text responses to appear on the line below any previous inputs? This is where I'm up to:

```
if(MasterOnOff.Checked == true)
{
FeedbackTextBox.Text = "Master Switch On";
}
if(MasterOnOff.Checked == false)
{
FeedbackTextBox.Text = "Master Switch Off";
}
```

Working in C# Windows Forms, any help massively appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a look at the answers to "Related" questions as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
multilineTextBox.Text += "Your message" + Environment.NewLine;
```

it´s equal to

```
multilineTextBox.Text = multilineTextBox.Text + "Your message" + Environment.NewLine;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of FeedbackTextBox.Text = "..." which replaces the text in your textbox, try to append to the end of it by using += instead:

```
FeedbackTextBox.Text += "Master Switch Off\n".
```

which is the same as

```
FeedbackTextBox.Text = FeedbackTextBox.Text + "Master Switch Off\n"
```

The \n part is just the character for new line so that it doesn't add everything as a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to the textbox code in the designer class:

`this.textBox1.Multiline = true;`